# Selenium. Execute a custom function on a WebDriveWait several times but throws TimeoutException

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, testing

I'm testing a webapp by using two `selenium` instances. Both instances reach at the same page with a table and several records. One instance get a record for editing; the second tries to get the same record but it receives a error message which it is expected. The testing code is below:

I use `pytest`

```py
def test_IngresoComunidad__dos_drivers__uno_edita__otro_accede_tras_timeout__misma_fila__return__driver_wire_accede_200(
    live_server, selenium, seleniumwire
):
    def tratar(seleniu):
        # Try to get the record. A modal is shown containing a error msg. 
        seleniu = acceder_mod_ing_editar(seleniu)
        acc_den_mod = seleniu.find_element(By.ID, "accDenModal")
        if acc_den_mod.is_displayed():
            # Dismiss the error modal.
            acc_den_mod.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
            return False
        else:
            edit_modal = seleniu.find_element(By.ID, 'editIngModal')
            return edit_modal.is_displayed()

    # START CONDITION. Firstly, log in 
    seleniumwire = paso_login(live_server, seleniumwire)
    selenium = paso_login(live_server, selenium)
    
    # Go to the page under test
    selenium = acceder_ingcom(live_server, selenium)
    seleniumwire = acceder_ingcom(live_server, seleniumwire)
    
    # FIRST INSTANCE
    # Get the record by clicking a dropdown button, then it show all options. Click on button 
    # 'editar' and a modal is shown.  
    acceder_mod_ing_editar(selenium)
    # SECOND INSTANCE. 
    # Try to get the same record as the first one. Before 120 seconds, it cannot get the record but after 120 seconds, it gets the record. 
    edit_mod_wire = WebDriverWait(seleniumwire, timeout=130, poll_frequency=2).until(tratar)
    assert edit_mod_wire
```

I think the `WebDriverWait` execute the function `tratar` every time until it succeeds after 120 seconds. The issue happens at the function below which is inside function `tratar`:

```py
def acceder_mod_ing_editar(selenium):
    try:
        dropd_btn = selenium.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ingresosTable tbody a.actions')
        dropd_btn1 = WebDriverWait(selenium, timeout=5).until(
             EC.element_to_be_clickable(dropd_btn[0])
        )
        actions = ActionChains(selenium)
        actions.move_to_element(dropd_btn1)
        actions.click(dropd_btn1)
        actions.perform()

        elms = selenium.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ingresosTable tbody a.editar' )
        # SECOND TIME. It fails here!
        elms1 = WebDriverWait(selenium, timeout=5).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(elms[0])
        )
        actions = ActionChains(selenium)
        actions.move_to_element(elms1)
        actions.click(elms1)
        actions.perform()
        return selenium
    except ElementNotInteractableException as eni:
        pytest.fail(eni.msg)
```

This function handles a dropdown button and the button 'Editar' which shows a modal for editing the record. The first execution time, it works seamless. The second time, after dismissing the error message, the function `acceder_mod_ing_editar` fails at finding again the button to show up the editing modal but before reaching here, the dropdown already worked. So here, the `TimeoutException` is raised.

I got `ElementClickInterceptedException` and `ElementNotInteractableException`, So I improved the function `acceder_mod_ing_editar` so far but I don't understand why the `TimeoutException` is raised there.

Please, help me to understand why that exception is happening there and how to solve it. I expect the function `tratar` executes every time until it gets the record.

Also, I'm open to new ideas about how to improve the test.